# How does android handle the +-sign in a phonenumber

Tags: android, android-intent, exit-code

I'm trying to call a calling card through code and want to send the following uri to the intent:

accessnumber+pause+phonenumber+#

The phonenumber comes from the addresslist, but how do I handle the + (as in exit code), because it's for example in the States 011, in Europe 00. And I guess I can't just send it to the intent. Is there a way to handle this?

Problem is that the calling card wants the plus as a 00 or a 011 for example.

```
String uri = "tel:" + Uri.encode(phonenumber)

try { 
                Intent intentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL); 
                intentCall.setData(Uri.parse(uri));  
                startActivity(intentCall);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)        { }
```

Comment: Why can't you just send it to the intent? Have you tried?

Comment: "Just trying" seems to me to be the source of a lot of buggy applications that rely on unofficially supported behaviour that isn't guaranteed to persist in different versions.  Checking the documentation is almost always better.

Comment: Furthermore, seeing if it works in this case would involve testing in multiple countries, which would be prohibitively expensive...

Comment: Jules, I've tried. The thing is I want to make this possible for multiple cards (so indeed there is the expensive testing factor) and the + doesn't work, it asks for the exit code, such as 00 or 011. I thought that Android almost must 'translate' the + into the exit code of the default locale, so there should be a method that returns the exit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android [is documented](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) to use [rfc3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) compatible telephone uris.  RFC3966 specifies that the '+' character is used for international dialling, so Android should recognize the '+' character and deal with it appropriately.

Comment: The problem is that I'm sending it after the calling card accessnumber, so I'll have to adjust it to the exit code. I hoped maybe android automatically adjusted the + to the exit code on that locale, is there a method for that?

Comment: Hmm... I see the problem.  The '+' character is only valid at the start of a number, so that isn't guaranteed to work (even if it does in some versions it may not in others).  How are you obtaining your calling card numbers?  Can you obtain the exit code the same way (conceivably, some calling card providers could use a different exit code to the user's local one, e.g. consider a user in europe calling through a card provider whose service is set up on the american standard, so asking the card provider what to do may just be the best thing)?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. Would have been nice if the sim for example had the exit code. Since now it is not compatible if it's another card.

Comment: Unfortunately the phone doesn't actually need to know this information (calls are established by sending a packet of the format described at http://www.informit.com/library/content.aspx?b=Signaling_System_No_7&seqNum=66, which as you can see has a 'type of address' field that specifies whether the number dialled is national or international), so it is unlikely Android actually knows the code.